# [PFFacebookUtils session].permissions doesn't have proper values

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement status updates to Facebook in an app I'm working on via Parse's Facebook api. Every time I check the permissions for the current session I never get what I need.

Here's the code I'm using to log in to Facebook

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"]
                            block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"Initial login permissions: %@", [[PFFacebookUtils session] permissions]);
                                [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:[PFUser currentUser]
                                          withPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                                        audience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                                           block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                                               NSLog(@"Post request login permissions: %@", [[PFFacebookUtils session] permissions]);
                                                           }];
                            }];
```

And here's the console output

```
2014-05-19 12:33:24.273 Uppd[3112:60b] Initial login permissions: (null)
2014-05-19 12:33:26.158 Uppd[3112:60b] Post request login permissions: (
status,
permission
)
```

First, why are the initial permissions null?? And second, what is 'status' and 'permission' in the post request permissions? I can't find any information about this problem.

I'm using

Parse SDK v1.2.19

Facebook SDK v3.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add this key to your permission array to be able to post for the user 
@"publish_actions"

So Permission array to be 
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"publish_actions"]